# C# Process.Start Argument with a dash fails to executr

Tags: c#, gnupg, process.start

I am having some trouble trying to work my way through some C# that I'm just not comfortable with. My issue appears to stem from a dash/hyphen in one of my parameters being passed to Process.Start(). In the below code the argument list is built from data in the database. The issue occurs when sRecipient has a dash. For example ***Bank-Name*** vs ***BankName***. Unfortunately, I can't remove the dash because it is the name of a public key provided by the bank.

```
 sGPGParms = " -e ";
 if (sUseGPGASCIIArmor.ToUpper() == "Y")
 {
      sGPGParms += "-a ";
 }
 sGPGParms += "-r \"" + sRecipient + "\" \"" + sDestinationDir + sFileName + "\"";
```

The next section of code is where things seem to fail. The program is using Process.Start() to pass the path and the parameters. The program does not fall into the fail condition and says that the file created successfully but it doesn't do anything. This code worked earlier today before the bank provided a new encryption key with a dash in the name. That dash is literally the only change. This code has worked since 2008 so I have isolated it to the arguments parameter in Process.Start() and how the dash is impacting things as the culprit.

```
Process myCmd;
               
if ((myCmd = Process.Start(Path, sGPGParms)) == null)
{
      LogEvent(sServerLogPath, "ERROR: GPG.exe failed to start", sUserName);
      SqlContext.Pipe.Send("GPG.exe failed to start");
}
else
{
      LogEvent(sServerLogPath, "Bank file created successfully", sUserName);
      SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Bann file created successfully");
      
}
```

As a side note, I can run the full command copied from the logging and it works. It only fails when passed through Process.Start().

This is the command that works manually but fails when passed through Process.Start() with no public key

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpg2.exe" -e -r "Bank-Name" "c:\public\BankPay.txt"
```

Any ideas why this dash is causing an issue?

UPDATE: Working through some of the suggestions in the comments I see that I am getting an exit code of 2 with the error public key not found. The key exists because I can run the command manually and can see it when I --list-keys

Comment: A couple of things that would be helpful to diagnose: what the program's exit code is, and what the output is (`stderr` and `stdout`). Adding a test block for `myCmd.ExitCode != 0` should allow for some more verbose logging. Also check out [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror) [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput).

Comment: Are you using OpenPGP by any chance? There's a section on their [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg2) (near the bottom) on how to specify the user ID, and it appears that hyphens are not valid word characters. You may need to specify the user ID in one of the other supported ways. In any case, the `Process` API passes the arguments directly to the process and doesn't do any filtering that would be sensitive to things like hyphens.

Comment: @JeffE We are using GNUpgp (gpg2.exe), if it didn't work when I manually run it in command prompt I would think the issue of not a valid character would be correct. However it does work manually.

Comment: Note this `sDestinationDir + sFileName` is a bad idea, better to use `Path.Combine` function

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't disagree. This code was written way before my time and I see several issues like that I plan to fix. None of that is really relevant until I can solve the key issue of why changing the public key from one without a dash to one with a dash broke things.

Comment: Does your luck change if you use shell execute? `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = Path, Arguments = sGPGParms, UseShellExecute = true } )` (and try `false` instead of `true` in case you're using .NET Framework instead of .NET Core).

Comment: @jeff E same result.

Comment: @joncloud ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError gives me " Bank-Name: skipped: No public key" , working on getting the standard output now since I know the key does indeed exist.

Comment: @johncoud The exit code is two, File Not Found. That seems to coincide with the standard error.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue of current working directory?

Comment: @BenVoigt I considered that actually. But dismissed it because all I have to do is change the key being used back to the one without the dash and things work fine again so I wasn't sure how the directory would impact it.

Comment: There might be a copy of the key-without-dash file in the other directory.  Just because you see one in the same place as key-with-dash does not mean it is the one being found.

Comment: Do not concantenate any paths, to be safe use `Path.Combine()` instead.

Comment: @RufusL Sorry that was actually from a bad copy-paste. I have corrected it.

Comment: Is the hyphen indeed [a hyphen](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002D), right after you read it from whatever data source into `sRecipient`, or is it only converted to that specific hyphen when you dump it in the log?

Comment: In both situations, e.g., when the C# program is run, when you run the console command directly, are the users the same? That could have an impact to what keys are available.

Comment: @joncloud yes the user is the same. I can swap back to the old key and the program runs without issue. A simple change to the new key causes the issues. The user doesn't change.